# How did they make the slider from tobaccobody.fi?

Tags: jquery, image, slider, mask

I am trying to understand how can I make a slider similar to the one from [tobaccobody.fi](http://tobaccobody.fi/m_en.php)

I think that they have 2 images and use the slider to mask them somehow.

No idea how could I name something like this... can you guys point me to a tutorial, or explain me how is this effect achieved?

Thank you!

Comment: they have to divs freshHolder and tuhkaHolder and change the width of tuhkaHolder with the slider

Comment: This breaks several SO rules on asking question, please read the [help]

Comment: As the question is right now, it is too broad. It requires too much research effort to answer, and would ultimately end with suggesting some tool or plugin. To get an idea what is used here, start by examining what scripts are loaded when you go to the page and examine the elements that are altered. Do some research on the plugins you find there and see if you see functionality you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sliding part

http://zurb.com/playground/twentytwenty

And here's another one: http://www.catchmyfame.com/2009/06/25/jquery-beforeafter-plugin/

I prefer the first link, it's more in the lines of what you're looking for